# HTC stuck at logo screen while entering recovery mode

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, adb, samsung, clockworkmod-recovery, htc

I want to install Kitkat 4.4.2 Rom to my HTC  Sensation XL android phone.
I followed instructions and I installed CWM (ClockWorkMod) but I can not enter recovery choice. When I click on that there occure HTC logo and just that no other thing.

Following picture is where I am.When I click the recovery choice I need to go Clock work mode screen. 
[image] 
But unfortunately my phone stucks at logo screen.
What I want to see is following picture to make it clear for you;

[image]
Thanks in advance..

Comment: I am still waiting with hope that someone will help me =)

Comment: Consider linking the instructions you followed to install CWM. What is your source (download) of CWM?